# How can I make Google Chrome display a plain text HTTP response, rather than downloading it in a file?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

There's a web site I visit that includes a document which is returned with content type text/plain and my version of Google Chrome used to display it in the browser window, as plain text.  I like it that way.  However, it has started to download the document now when I visit it, instead, meaning I have to open it with a text editor to view it.  How can I make Chrome return to the old behaviour?

Comment: Try clearing your temp files and cache.

Comment: Are you sure other browsers don't download it as well? The server might tell them to do so. Peek into the headers using the Web Inspector. Or give us a URL?

Answer (score 8):

The reason is most likely that the server is telling the client (browser) to download the file. This is controlled (usually) via the HTTP header

```
Content-disposition: attachment
```

(optionally with a filename).

Check if the server serves your document with this header. To view the headers, you can download the page using a tool that preserves HTTP headers (e.g. `wget --save-headers`), or use an online service, e.g. http://web-sniffer.net/ .

Then post the headers here, or even better, the document's URL (if you can).

Comment: So, assuming this is the case, how can you have the browser ignore this option and simply display the file instead of trying to save it?

Comment: Answer to my own question: http://superuser.com/questions/199382/make-chrome-always-open-pdfs-itself

Answer (score 7):

You could try doing

> view-source:http://example.com/the-text-document.txt

Which should let you see the document in chrome regardless of the headers

Comment: Nope. I just tried that.

Comment: I think this trick only works in Firefox.

Comment: Works just fine in Chrome (24).

Answer (score 6):

Can you verify that the Content-Type is actually 'text/plain'?  You can do so in by going to View -> Developer -> Developer Tools and viewing the response headers on the file.  I've seen situations where the Content-Type is unrecognized (i.e. 'plain/text'), and therefore causes the file to be downloaded rather than displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that you check your url with other browser if it's working so may be you are facing this google [Chrome issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=106150)
Here is an example URL showing the issue: http://uselesstrash.com/test.txt
Try this URL with Firefox, then Chrome and you'll see the behavior is different because of the hidden "^G": 
`test^Gtext`.

If your text is utf-8 encoded but has some lower-ascii chars in it (e.g., ESC) that might be triggering the issue.

If other browsers act the same as Chrome you have to check if the MIME type really is plain/text, use a web sniffer to verify the header content.
Just do a "CTRL + SHIFT + i" in Chrome, then go to the "Network" tab.

Comment: I second the first part of this answer.  Chrome will display a text file in a tab, unless it has some 'special characters' in it, and then it will shift to downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

What Chrome plugins do you have installed? There is a similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381152/chrome-downloads-page-instead-of-showing

The solution was an issue with this plugin:

> I've solved the problem! It was caused by the Webug 1.2.3 FirePHP
>   extension for Google Chrome. Don't know if future versions of this
>   plugin also have this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of 2021, Chrome and Edge will treat any response from the server as an attachment if it includes any illegal characters even if you have specified "Content-Disposition: inline" and/or "Content-Type: text/plain". More sensibly Mozilla will display the response with a warning messag rather than ignore the explicit instructions from the server.