# Disable "Content-Disposition: attachment" and force inline display

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download

Websites which use `Content-Disposition: attachment` force me to download the document which I dislike.

For example I want to print out the invoices of my ISP for taxation purposes. Their stupid website forces me to download twelve PDF files like `5834886-1_104679449.pdf`. These clutter up my download folder. Even worse if the link is not informative enough and I need to check the document by opening it.

How can I disable `Content-Disposition:attachment` and force my browser to use inline display of the PDF? If I want to save the file, I can do it from the browser menu or press <kbd>Control</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

I am using Google Chrome on OS X, but I would like to have a generic solution working for all browsers and operating systems, if possible.

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/199382/make-chrome-always-open-pdfs-itself

Comment: This is currently a "won't fix" issue in the Chromium issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67643 Using one of the linked Chrome extensions is probably the only solution to this, for now.

Comment: Or try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/undisposition?hl=en

Comment: @nalply Thank you, Undisposition works beautifully. You should write that as an answer :)

Comment: @PiDelport Cannot view bug id `67643`. I get a `Permission denied` page.

Answer (score 13):

For everyone still looking for a proper solution, try this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/undisposition?hl=en

Credits to [comment from nalply](https://superuser.com/questions/692168/disable-content-disposition-attachment-and-force-inline-display?newreg=135f068d2c9540e395e499e12413b7fa#comment1040992_692168)

Comment: A similar approach, described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/755252/280128), uses the [Modify Content-Type](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka?hl=en-US) extension. That one has a slightly higher set-up complexity but it allows to restrict the changes to pre-specified domains.

Answer (score 3):

Not a generic solution, but for those looking for a Firefox solution there is an addon called *[Inline Disposition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition/)*.