# Always open pdfs in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When you open an URL in chrome that leads to a PDF, the way Chrome deals with it depends on the way the server sends it. If the server serves the pdf as an attachment (using the [`content-disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header), chrome opens a "save" dialog. Otherwise, the PDF will be shown "inline", as the web page. I often want to view pdf but don't care about having them on my hard drive. Is there a way to tell chrome, or another browser, to show a pdf inline, when it is sent as an attachment? In other words, can I tell Chrome to ignore the content-dispotion header for certain requests?

Comment: Related: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/755252/109256) in older post hinted that there is Chrome extension called "Modify Content-Type".

Answer (score 0):

The [PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?hl=en) extension doesn't have great reviews, and I haven't used it a lot yet, but the first time I tried it on a pdf that Chrome previously prompted to download it was displayed in the browser.

Possibly better, [No PDF Download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-pdf-download/ikhahkidgnljlniknmendeflkdlfhonj/) uses Chrome's viewer rather than a third-party viewer.